# How to replicate Robo3T SSH configuration in nodejs and connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, robo3t

I can connect to MongoDB with Robo-3T with SSH tunnel. But I fail to replicate the connection with Node.
This is the Robo-3T configuration

[image: Connection]

[image: SSH]

And this is my code. It seems that the SSH connection is ok, but the `MongoClient.connect` fails.

```
var config = {
    username:'biomec',
    Password:'xxxxxx',
    host:'10.0.0.244',
    port:22,
    dstPort:27017,
    localHost:'localhost',
    localPort: 27017
};

var tunnel = require('tunnel-ssh');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var server = tunnel(config, function (error, server) {
   if(error){
     console.log("SSH connection error: " + error);
   }
  console.log('SSH ok');
  MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017", function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
       console.log("Mongodb connection error: " + error);
     }
     console.log("We are connected to MONGO");
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you verify that the tunnel is indeed up by checking with the OS (e.g. `netstat -nlp` on *nix)?

Comment: @mscdex The tunnel is up because it works with Robo-3T

Comment: I was referring to when you create the tunnel programmatically in node via `tunnel-ssh`. It appears that when you're connecting via "Robo-3T", it's setting up its own ssh tunnel separately.

Comment: @mscdex, you are right. The tunnel in node via `tunnel-ssh` is not connected. I confess that I have not experience with SSH. How I can reproduce the behaviour of "Robo-3T"

Comment: Are you seeing an error being logged to the console? I think `Password` should be `password` (lowercase). I know that's what `tunnel-ssh`'s example shows, but I believe that's a typo.

Comment: @mscdex , you are right. I was a typo. Thanks.